# Are Jackson mapped objects DAOs?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jackson

I'm using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to map JSON to a Java object.

Is the created Java object a DAO since its an object representation of the JSON structure and so is providing access to the JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, i would say its a [data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

DAOs are used to [persist data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a DAO design pattern.
DAO pattern stands for providing the access to the Data Layer.

I will rather say it Value Object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mapping from one instance to another instance, I think you are using more of a Converter or Adapter (take a look at the adapter pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)).

To my knowledge, the purpose of the `DAO` (Data Access Object) is to provide a layer, or an object, which provides some sort of access to your data storage.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [Memento](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MementoPattern), for "*Without violating encapsulation, capture and externalize an object's internal state so that the object can be restored to this state later*" I wouldn't argue with calling it Value Object but it's definitly not a DAO which the defining characteristic is the abstraction of a persistent data story.